# what are the signatures for alloc,init,NSobject

Tags: iphone

im new to iphone development here i dont the signatures of these methods like ,alloc,init and nsobject,nsstring.

can any one please help me for these signatures.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use apple documentation for this.

```
-(id)init;

+ (id)alloc;


NSObject *tempObject = [[NSObjectalloc]init];
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]init];
```